# Running openshift origin on mac 10.11.6 with docker version 1.12.0

Tags: macos, docker, openshift-origin

Running origin on a rhel system i use the following command line.

```
sudo docker run -d --name "origin" --privileged --pid=host 
--net=host -v /:/rootfs:ro -v /var/run:/var/run:rw 
-v /sys:/sys -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:rw 
-v /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes:/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes 
openshift/origin start
```

When i run it on my mac i get this fault

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: ore info.
.
ath /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes
is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File Sharing.
See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces for m.
```

How should the command line look on osx?

Links:

[Docker](https://www.docker.com/products/docker)

[Origin - running-in-a-docker-container](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/getting_started/administrators.html#running-in-a-docker-container)

Solution: 
After trial and error i got i started by first creating the directories and than executed the following command.

```
sudo docker run -d --name "origin" --privileged --pid=host 
--net=host -v /:/rootfs:ro -v /var/run:/var/run:rw 
-v /sys:/sys -v /private/var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:rw 
-v /private/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes:/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes 
openshift/origin start
```

Unfortunately there is still a lot of errors in the log. :-/

Update:

It seems like it works "almost".

```
oc status
In project default on server https://172.17.0.2:8443

svc/kubernetes - 172.30.0.1 ports 443, 53->8053, 53->8053

View details with 'oc describe <resource>/<name>' or list everything with 'oc get all'.
```

In order to be able to reach the console i had to add an alias to the network interface.

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 172.17.0.2
```

Now i can reach the console at https:// 172.17.0.2:8443/console/

Comment: We have not tested on 1.12 yet (both OpenShift and Kubernetes are fairly conservative in Docker versions in order to gain as much soak time on fixes as possible).   Please file issues if can.  Also, have you tried with "oc cluster up"?

Answer (score 0):

**Docker Mac Native** (which I assume you´re using because of the version number 1.12.x) is the successor of docker-machine with VirtualBox and brings up a new Mac only [concept of sharing file system with your Docker containers](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/).

So in your case, the Open Shift Origin container needs access to **/var/lib/origin**. You have to add this folder to your filesystem (e.g. via `sudo mkdir /var/lib/origin`) and change the owner to your username (`sudo chown yourUserName /var/lib/origin`). Then add this folder /var/lib/origin to your Docker Configuration via clicking on the small docker logo in your Mac menu bar and selecting **Preferences...** / **File Sharing**.

This should help you with the "Mounts denied"-Error.

Comment: i am stuck at the same error. actually docker has mounting **/private** by default. **/var** is only a symlink to **/private/var** - so i think, there is toublemaker. - docker doesn't use the symlink correct.